# can a doctor visit a patient?

Tags: word-choice

I read somewhere that when you visit someone you go to their place that they're at. I'm not sure if it applies to a doctor, too.

Considering that you were supposed to go to the doctor's office, is this sentence right?

'The doctor has cancelled your appointment. He won't be able to visit you today.'

If not, when the doctor is supposed to see you at home, can we say he's going to visit you?

Comment: Note that this might depend on location. In the US, *house calls* by doctors are pretty much completely obsolete: patients *only* go to the doctor, not the other way around. But in other places, it may still be common for doctors to go to patients' homes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an idiomatic usage, but we would say:

> The doctor has cancelled your appointment. He won't be able to **see** you today.

Your example also won't work because it implies he is visiting you (at your house). In this sense, you are visiting him.

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure if I understand you. So a doctor doesn't visit people, it's people who visit him. Right?